# CS0016 error running web application in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-7

I have a Web service application developed using VS2013. .Net framework 4.5. I published it to my local IIS and now get the following error:

> for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5 Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> error CS0016: Could not write to output file
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\ims\aa5f2280\45739e94\App_global.asax.qoc3weqj.dll' -- 'The
>   directory name is invalid. '

It was working a few months ago. I have installed VS2015 community edition since then and can think of no other significant changes that could possibly affect my environment.

I have googled CS0016 relating to web apps extensively and read many SO postings. The main advice appears to be about granting the correct permissions to various temporary directories and Temporary ASP.Net files. I have given permissions to every temporary directory that might be involved %tmp%, %temp%, %windir%\tmp, %windir%\temp and others that I don't immediately recall. These were granted to IIS_IUSRS, DefaultAppPool, IUSR and NETWORK SERVICE. The multiplicity of users granted permissions is mainly out of frustration. I have also looked at the event concerning this error. An example of the header is provided below. As you can see from the process information that the account name is IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool and I have given every directory I can think of access to that.

I have reinstalled IIS through Programs and Features and have uninstalled and reinstalled ASP.Net using aspnet_regiis a couple of times. I have also switched off my ESET NOD virus checker and windows firewall. None of which has made a dot of difference. I have that feeling that I have missed something really simple but I am at my wits end.

Sorry for the long post but I wanted to give as much info as I could. Any suggestions are very welcome.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          17/08/2015 18:03:49
Event ID:      1310
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Meridian5
Description:
Event code: 3007 
Event message: A compilation error has occurred. 
Event time: 17/08/2015 18:03:49 
Event time (UTC): 17/08/2015 17:03:49 
Event ID: 4a02b6c6a53c43dcb589b367bf360146 
Event sequence: 3 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/ims-3-130843046283556791 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /ims 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ims\ 
    Machine name: MERIDIAN5 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 2628 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
```

Comment: Do your IIS have execute permission assigned to that specific site!?

Comment: Please confirm in the site configuration that the execute permission is assigned.. also if it is hosted site, you have to have separate directory named `temp` in site; as you will not be able to use server's %temp%.

Comment: The default web site does have execute permission. I am using my local IIS. I have C:\temp and C:tmp to which the temp and tmp environment variables are pointing. I have in the past pointed them at %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp. All folders have full permissions assigned to IIS_IUSRS and DefaultAppPool. All folders have been deleted and created a number of times.

Comment: check if any recent hot fix is installed!! that might be a strance result

Comment: Many updates but nothing obvious. Looking at Procmon it seems that w3wp is writing files to subfolders of Temporary ASP.NET files\ims\xxx\yyy\assembly and hash

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am having the same issue.